# RethinkDB: /usr/bin/rethinkdb: Permission denied on startup

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, rethinkdb

I'm having a problem with init.d script on my Raspberry PI 4 (4GB) with Raspbian 10.

I've followed the guide on the [official docs](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/raspbian/) and compiled RethinkDB without any problem.
Then I've configured as described in the [Deployment docs](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/start-on-startup/).

1. Created conf file in `/etc/rethinkdb/instances.d/<conf_name>.conf`;
2. Copied init.d script `sudo cp /home/pi/rethinkdb-2.4.1/packaging/assets/init/rethinkdb /etc/init.d/rethinkdb`
3. Added Default Runlevel `sudo update-rc.d rethinkdb defaults`

I can start the server with command `rethinkdb --config-file /etc/rethinkdb/instances.d/instance1.config` and it gives me no problem

```
pi@homeserverpi:~ $ rethinkdb --config-file /etc/rethinkdb/instances.d/instance1.conf
WARNING: ignoring --server-name because this server already has a name.
Running rethinkdb 2.4.1 (CLANG 7.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_701/final))...
Running on Linux 5.4.72-v7l+ armv7l
Loading data from directory /home/pi/rethinkdb_data
Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8182
Listening on cluster addresses: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.3, ::1, fe80::38b8:6928:e4fd:1a9c%3
Listening on driver addresses: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.3, ::1, fe80::38b8:6928:e4fd:1a9c%3
Listening on http addresses: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.3, ::1, fe80::38b8:6928:e4fd:1a9c%3
Server ready, "homeserverpi_9x0" 00eb027b-181c-4a15-a170-8ba8299f4f3f
```

But when I try to start the service it gives me this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rethinkdb start                            rethinkdb: instance1: Starting instance. (logging to '/var/lib/rethinkdb/instance1/data/log_file')
    /etc/init.d/rethinkdb: 224: /etc/init.d/rethinkdb: /usr/bin/rethinkdb: Permission denied
```

Permissions

```
pi@homeserverpi:~ $ ls -alh /etc/init.d/rethinkdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7.5K Nov 30 00:20 /etc/init.d/rethinkdb


pi@homeserverpi:~ $ ls -alh /usr/bin/rethinkdb/
total 40K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov 29 23:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  36K Nov 29 23:06 ..
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Thank you